# How to print the names of the files counted?

Tags: perl

I am new to PERL and have gotten my first useful script to work!  Now I would like to enhance it but do not understand how use the arrays to achieve my goal.  I have read numerous articles and posts, but just do not understand yet.

The script that I have working counts the number of files in a given directory of a given extension and prints the number out.  What I would like it to also do is to print the filenames to a .txt file in the initial specified directory.

Any advice or input is appreciated!  I am sure I need to use an array to achieve this goal, I just do not understand how to feed the counted file names into it.  I am able to print out the array list, I just need some help fillng the array up!  Many thanks!

The script in its current state:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use File::Find;

print "\n\n";
print "This script will start at the given directory and\nrecursively count the files of a given type\n\n\n";
print "-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n";
print "What directory would you like to start the count?\n\nDirectory Path: ";
my $dir = <STDIN>; #directory to begin search
chomp $dir;

print "\nWhat is the file extension you are searching for?\n\nFile Extension(.htm, .plx, .txt, etc.): ";
my $filext = <STDIN>; #file extension we're searching for
chomp $filext;

my $count = 0;


find(sub{$count++ if $File::Find::name =~ /$filext$/}, $dir);



     if ($count > 0){
     print "\n$count files counted, \n"; #display the number of files counted with the given file extension in the given directory

     }

     else {
     print "Couldn't find any files to count.\n"; #if no files of the given type are found in the given directory
     }
```

UPDATE:

Thank you Wes.  I see how that works now and thank you for taking the time to respond.

For anyone who is interested, here is the final code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use File::Find;

print "\n\n";
print "This script will start at the given directory and\nrecursively count the files of a given type\n\n\n";
print "-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n";
print "What directory would you like to start the count?\n\nDirectory Path: ";
my $dir = <STDIN>; #directory to begin search
chomp $dir;

print "\nWhat is the file extension you are searching for?\n\nFile Extension(.htm, .plx, .txt, etc.): ";
my $filext = <STDIN>; #file extension we're searching for
chomp $filext;

my $count = 0;
my @files;
find(sub{
    if ($File::Find::name =~ /$filext$/) {
        push @files, $File::Find::name;
        $count++;
    }
}, $dir);



     if ($count > 0){
     print "\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n";
     print "\n$count files counted: \n\n"; #display the number of files counted with the given file extension in the given directory
     foreach (@files){
         print "$_\n";
     }


     }

     else {
     print "Couldn't find any files to count.\n"; #if no files of the given type are found in the given directory
     }
```

Comment: Hi, we usually just call it 'Perl' now. All-caps PERL makes it look like an acronym, humorous possibilities notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That anonymous sub you pass to `find` can execute more than one statement, just like a normal sub.

```
my @files;
find(sub{
    if ($File::Find::name =~ /$filext$/) {
        push @files, $File::Find::name;
        $count++;
    }
}, $dir);
```

You can also just check the size of an array like this: `my $count = scalar @files;` instead of keeping a separate count

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I see what you mean about keeping a separate count.  Your response helped me get it working as desired!

Answer (score 1):

This program will do what you want. There is no need for an array as you can print the file names to the list file as they are encountered by `find`.

The main differences are:

- Open an output file to write the list of file names to, before calling `find`
- Print each file name to the new file as it is found by `find`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

print "

This script will start at the given directory and
recursively count the files of a given type


-----------------------------------------------------------


What directory would you like to start the count?

Directory Path: ";

my $dir = <STDIN>;
chomp $dir;

print "
What is the file extension you are searching for?

File Extension(.htm, .plx, .txt, etc.): ";

my $filext = <STDIN>;
chomp $filext;

STDOUT->autoflush;

open my $out, '>', "$dir/file_list.txt" or die $!;
my $count = 0;
find(sub {
    return unless /\Q$filext\E$/;
    print $out "$_\n";
    $count++;
}, $dir);

if ($count > 0) {
    print "\n$count files counted\n";
}
else {
    print "Couldn't find any files to count\n";
}
```